# CSS Display inline property is not working for me

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align the `section` element as shown below

[image]

in a row by applying the `display: inline-block;` property and this is what I see

[image]

For some reason I can't seem to get it to work. I have included both HTML and CSS code below.

It will be great help if someone could please advice.

```css
body {
 background-color: #edeff2;
 margin: 25px;
}

header {
 margin-top: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 padding-top: 8px;
 background-color: #b8babc;
 text-align: center;
  color: #111; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: -1px; line-height: 1; text-align: center;
 /*I copied the above style from https://wdexplorer.com/20-examples-beautiful-css-typography-design/ */
}

nav {
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
 border: 1px solid;
}

h2 {
 color: #111; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: -1px; line-height: 1;

}

section {
 display: inline-block;
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 2%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

progress {
  color: #5ff4ef;
  font-size: .7em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-indent: .5em;
  width: 15em;
  height: 1.8em;
  border: 1px solid #5ff4ef;
  background: #5ff4ef;
}

details {
 font-size: 1.2em;
 color: #028402;
}

details p {
 font-style: italic;
}

footer {
 background-color: #b8babc;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 clear: both;
}

img {
 width: 105px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Colleen</title>
   <!-- ADD a LINK TO YOUR STYLE SHEET HERE!! -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
     <h1>ALOK</h1>
     <nav>
       <a href = "">One</a>
       <a href = "">Two</a>
       <a href = "">Three</a>
       <a href = "">Four</a>
     </nav>
  </header>
   <section class="half">
      <h2>Favorite Foods</h2>
      <ul>
         <li>Apples</li>
         <li>Pizza</li>
         <li>Crab</li>
         <li>Chocolate Cake</li>
      </ul>
   </section>
  
    <section class="half">
      <h2>Achievements</h2>
        <p> Progress in this course (100%)</100%><progress value = "1"></progress><br/>Progress in the Specialization (20%) <progress max = "5" value = "1"></progress><br/>  Progress in life goals (67%)<progress max = "100" value = "67"></progress></p>
    </section>

    <section class = "whole">
      <h2>More About Me</h2>
      <details open><summary>My Childhood</summary>
      <p>I grew up in Bangalore India.  I lived near a Mango Grove and I used to steal a lot of them. </details>
    </section>
 
     <footer>
      <p><img src = "http://www.intro-webdesign.com/images/newlogo.png" alt = "logo"/> This page was created by your name &amp; Colleen van Lent.   To learn more about web design, visit <a href="http://www.intro-webdesign.com">Intro to Web Design</a>.</p>
   </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't see the half or whole classes.

Comment: It looks like it's working to me. What do you want to happen?

Comment: I want the "More About Me" to align in the same row as "Favorite Foods" and "Achievements"

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? Could you please more elaborate

Comment: Then it works fine @AlokY

Comment: @ Prabhakaran I have included the screenshot.

Comment: Also include what you are getting as output. Because it works fine for me

Comment: You have an incorrect `</100%>` closing tag. It will probably have no effect, but still. And please try using the 'Tidy' button in the Snippet Editor. Your code works here as well, except that one text is so long that it tends to cause wrapping downward for of the entire section that it is in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes in your html and css of section tag. It'll work for you

```css
section.half {
 display: inline-block;
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 2%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
   <section class="half">
      <h2>Favorite Foods</h2>
      <ul>
         <li>Apples</li>
         <li>Pizza</li>
         <li>Crab</li>
         <li>Chocolate Cake</li>
      </ul>
   </section>
  
    <section class="half">
      <h2>Achievements</h2>
        <p> Progress in this course (100%)</100%><progress value = "1"></progress><br/>Progress in the Specialization (20%) <progress max = "5" value = "1"></progress><br/>  Progress in life goals (67%)<progress max = "100" value = "67"></progress></p>
    </section>

    <section class = " half whole">
      <h2>More About Me</h2>
      <details open><summary>My Childhood</summary>
      <p>I grew up in Bangalore India.  I lived near a Mango Grove and I used to steal a lot of them. </details>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `width`, like `30%`:

```css
body {
 background-color: #edeff2;
 margin: 25px;
}

header {
 margin-top: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 padding-top: 8px;
 background-color: #b8babc;
 text-align: center;
  color: #111; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: -1px; line-height: 1; text-align: center;
 /*I copied the above style from https://wdexplorer.com/20-examples-beautiful-css-typography-design/ */
}

nav {
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
 border: 1px solid;
}

h2 {
 color: #111; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: -1px; line-height: 1;

}

section {
 display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 2%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

progress {
  color: #5ff4ef;
  font-size: .7em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-indent: .5em;
  width: 15em;
  height: 1.8em;
  border: 1px solid #5ff4ef;
  background: #5ff4ef;
}

details {
 font-size: 1.2em;
 color: #028402;
}

details p {
 font-style: italic;
}

footer {
 background-color: #b8babc;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 clear: both;
}

img {
 width: 105px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Colleen</title>
   <!-- ADD a LINK TO YOUR STYLE SHEET HERE!! -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
     <h1>ALOK</h1>
     <nav>
       <a href = "">One</a>
       <a href = "">Two</a>
       <a href = "">Three</a>
       <a href = "">Four</a>
     </nav>
  </header>
   <section class="half">
      <h2>Favorite Foods</h2>
      <ul>
         <li>Apples</li>
         <li>Pizza</li>
         <li>Crab</li>
         <li>Chocolate Cake</li>
      </ul>
   </section>
  
    <section class="half">
      <h2>Achievements</h2>
        <p> Progress in this course (100%)</100%><progress value = "1"></progress><br/>Progress in the Specialization (20%) <progress max = "5" value = "1"></progress><br/>  Progress in life goals (67%)<progress max = "100" value = "67"></progress></p>
    </section>

    <section class = "whole">
      <h2>More About Me</h2>
      <details open><summary>My Childhood</summary>
      <p>I grew up in Bangalore India.  I lived near a Mango Grove and I used to steal a lot of them. </details>
    </section>
 
     <footer>
      <p><img src = "http://www.intro-webdesign.com/images/newlogo.png" alt = "logo"/> This page was created by your name &amp; Colleen van Lent.   To learn more about web design, visit <a href="http://www.intro-webdesign.com">Intro to Web Design</a>.</p>
   </footer>

</body>

</html>
```